# Read a data file containing objects of 2 diff. classes

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program for managing the stock details of a book store. It sells both books and their audio cassette versions. My defined classes are:

```
class stock

{
char title[30],author[15];
float price; int stockpos;
char version[5];

protected:

void getdata(); void putdata();
void defvers(char a[])  {strcpy(version,a);}//used to identify book & tape
void rettitle(char a[]) {strcpy(a,title);}
void retauthor(char a[]){strcpy(a,author);}
void retvers(char a[])  {strcpy(a,version);}/* all these used to obtain title, 
author, and whether its a book/tape to compare with the given details while searching*/
```

};

Here I have defined a class stock for the common data members and functions and derived 2 classes book and tape for defining the unique data members.

```
class book:public stock

{
int pagecount;

public:
book()   {  pagecount=0; defvers("book");    } //ctor
void getdata();
void putdata();

};

class tape:public stock

{
float duration; char readby[15];
public:
tape()    {  duration=0.00; defvers("tape");  }//ctor
void getdata();
void putdata();
```

};

I'm using a single data file stock.dat and storing the details of both books and tapes to it.

Now, what has me stumped is how to define a class function in stock that would display all details of either books or tapes, depending upon the user's choice, from that single data file stock.dat. Seeing as both book and tape classes would have different sizes, how can I manipulate the file.read()?
Or am I going the wrong way and should just create 2 seperate data files books.dat and tapes.dat, not caring that it would lengthen the source code?

Please help me out here.
~Athira

edit:
Yes I do have a field for specifying whether it's a book or a tape. its 'version[5]' defined in the class stock. The problem area for me is that the objects of derived classes book and tape, which I'm using to write to the binary data, file have different sizes.

The contents in the file would somewhat be like:

book  (of size x)
book  (of size x)

tape  (of size y)

book  (of size x)

tape  (of size y)
tape  (of size y)

Then how can I read only the tape objects and display them?

EDIT:
***Thank you Alwin, Pita and Retired Ninja for answering my questions.Your input has been very valuable to me. I learned things and got many ideas on how to create my project. I'm truly grateful to you for taking time to help me and patiently answering my questions. Once again, Thank you all.***

Comment: Is your file text or binary formatted?  Either way you can save the type of object to be read next and then handle it appropriately.

Comment: question updated. Please check it out.

Comment: Well, I don't know what your file looks like, but hopefully you write the type first so it can be checked without reading anything else.  If you only want to read the tapes you'll most likely need to read everything and just discard the parts you don't want.  If the records are a fixed size for each type you might also try seeking past them once you identify it is something you don't need, but just reading it is probably just as fast if not faster.

Comment: But the problem is that the book class contains only one extra data member(of int type) while the tape class has 2 diff data members(1 float and string member). So both kinds ofobjects have diff. size. If I tried to read an object of tape class using file.read((char*)&bookb, size of(bookb)); wouldn't that throw up an error?

Comment: If you store both in the same file you will need a more sophisticated serialization method than just saving/loading each struct as a blob.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on putting the data in 1 file, it would probably be a good idea to add a field to your data called something like 'type' that identifies which data is stored in this object.

but i would definitely recommend putting it in two different files as it will make many things easier, also makes the code better looking.

and why are you not using any returns if this is C++?

Comment: I agree with Alwin Leering that what you are trying to do is write the low-level code of a database, which is not something thats easy to do. With binary files you cannot do something like `getLine()` read here http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/textvsbinary.html

just curious, is this a school project? My recommendation is definitely to use a regular csv file instead of binary for this kind of operations or to use SQLite.

Comment: Yes, it is a school project. My +1,+2 course doesn't even mention csv files, so I'm blank at how to manipulate the csv. Is it like text files?

Comment: @user3040670 csv files are comma separated values, the format is similar to a spread sheet table, rows are separated by newlines and columns are separated by commas

Answer (score 0):

If your book store will only have tapes and books for the lifetime of your program, by all means go easy on yourself and create two files. If you anticipate your book store to sell different types of items in the future and they expect you to expand your application to take this into account you are better of using a versioning strategy.

A lot depends how you organise your object internally in your application. Are you holding your objects in vectors or are you using arrays (from the fact that you are using `char a[]` in you function signatures and are using strcpy I get the distinct impression that you are a C coder and would thus use arrays). Are you using multiple arrays or a single array?

Instead of the two classes it might be more instructive to show the essence of your loading/storing function(s), but the basic theory is to store some marker/identifier followed by your object. When you read the file back in you read the marker first and create an object of the corresponding type after which you can initialise this object by streaming the object data in.
Another solution would be to stream all objects of one type first, followed by all objects of the next type (with a marker in between)

Good luck.

[EDIT]

What you are describing is a low level database access layer implementation. Given the difficulty of this topic, there are scores of very well paid programmers who spend years to get this right and efficient.

So either this is a learning exercise or you're on the wrong track. Don't reinvent the wheel and use what's out there.
Given what you have told me so far I understand that this application's database will be small and operating under low load conditions. You have also indicated you would like your data stored in one file.

I suggest you look into SQLite, a free database access layer system. You can get it complete with source code to learn from and incorporate into your program.

Good luck

Comment: I'm using arrays to receive user choices like "book" "tape" and also extract things like author to compare with during searching. Like, retauthor() would copy the name of the author stored inside the object being read to a string rauthor so that I can do "if rauthor of the currently read object is equal to sauthor given by user, then display that object".

Comment: I made books and tapes as seperate classes because a tape/audiobook would be a given minutes long and voiced by someone, which is not applicable to books. Similarly, an audiobook wouldn't have no. of pages, which a book as. If I had made a single class represent both books and tapes, then for one kind, some fields would have to be left empty, which I'm not sure if it's allowed.

Comment: I actually don't know how to read only a specific member of an object from a file, even if it is the first one :(  All I know is to read the full object using file.read() function.                                                       If I decide to stick with a single file and store books in the 1st half and tapes in the last half, then how can I seperate the both halves? can I do it by writing an empty or predefined object as a seperator?

Comment: Re your first comment: Just to get it clear in my head... The list of books and tapes, are they only in the file or are they stored in memory. In other words if you are trying to find a book of a certain author, do you have to search through a disk file, loading each object and comparing it?

Comment: Re second comment, yes, empty (non-initialised or default initialised) fields are allowed in C++ classes, just like a struct in C can have a field member with garbage in it. Re third comment: the tag does not need to be a member of your class. You can write anything to a file even a tag string for example.

Comment: Re1: Yes, loading and comparing each object.                      Re2/3: Just to be clear, So if we'reusing a tag string, then in file it would be like:                                                      this is a book    (details of thebook)                              this is a tape      (details of the tape).                         Then while reading, first read the string, if it matches the 1st string, file.read() the obj using book b, otherwise file.read() the object using tape t.  Am I getting it right?

Comment: And...To search a tape, first read the string(using file.getline() ? ) , and if that line says its a book, then all I have to do is file.seekg(sizeof(bookb),ios::curr); right?

Comment: If I want to have a function `purchase(int order)` which would do `stockpos-=order; cout<<"price*order;` should I declare it as a class method,or as an independent function?    And in order to make the change reflect in the file, is using these statements                `int pos=fin.tellg();
fin.seekp(pos-sizeof( book or tape));
fin.write((char*)&book or tape,sizeof(book or tape));` as the rest of the code of the function correct? If I'm declaring the fn as a class method, I should use 'this' pointer instead of book or tape?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's start from the beginning. As this is a school project the amount of records will be very small. So what you can do is read the complete file into memory. Now what you do is have a variable in your stock class, denoting whether it's a book or a tape.

You define a stock pointer to the first record and check the type variable. You can now define book pointer or a tape pointer to point at the same memory location.

You will find the next record by moving the stock pointer forward by the size of your derived class.

This is extremely crude and would never stand in real world applications but it might do for your school project.

As an aside, you seem to be writing C code and trying to fit it in a C++ jacket. Maybe you would be more comfortable writing your application in C using structs. This might make things more familiar/obvious for you.

Good luck.